# Run three different cron jobs twice in hour

Tags: cron

I want to run three cron jobs commands twice per hour (once every half hour) and the interval between these command should be 1-2 minutes. How should I configure cron jobs from cpanel?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

I can't speak for cpanel, I'm afraid, but the crontab entries (if you can get to those) should look like this:

```
1,31 * * * *  /path/job1
3,33 * * * *  /path/job2
5,35 * * * *  /path/job3
```

That'll run each twice an hour, at 1, 3, and 5 minutes past the hour and half-hour.

Comment: Will the interval change from 2 to 3 minutes in this case: 1,31 * * * * /path/job1 4,33 * * * * /path/job2 7,35 * * * * /path/job3

Comment: It'll change to three minutes for the ones that run after the hour, but not the ones that run after the half-hour.  Try 1,31 / 4,34 / 7,37 for both.  It's just the number of minutes past the hour that each job should run, with each job running at two different times past each hour - do you see the logic?

Answer (score 3):

The interval between starting the jobs should be 2 minutes, or the interval from after one finishes 'til the next one starts should be 2 minutes?

If it's the first case, see MadHatter's comment.

If it's the second case, it's easiest to wrap the whole thing in a shell script, and do `sleep 120` in between.

I'll often do this if the next task shouldn't fire off if the previous task didn't return cleanly.  It also makes it easier to set a semaphore for the whole group of tasks so if a task gets hung, the next time it runs, you don't kick off the tasks again.

Comment: What Joe said, for the second case.  Good point, Joe!